# Use of deprecated PHP4 style class constructor is not supported since PHP 7 while using construct

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7.2, php4

I have several lines of code in my widgets.php that are showing an error.

This is a sample of the code I found at the given location and error:

```
function asp_testimonail_rotator_widget() {
    parent::__construct( false, 'ASP: Random Testimonial' );
}
```

I saw a previous thread that solved the error by adding the "_construct", but my code already has it in there.  How do I go about fixing that?

Thanks!

Comment: where is your class definition? and parent class definition?

Comment: The class has a method that is named the same as the class itself. You'll need to rename that method.

Comment: As Alex pointed out it is not enough to add properly named constructor, you need to remove/rename the old constructor too.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I would rather guess that the class itself is named `asp_testimonail_rotator_widget`, so the problem would be in this class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of deprecated PHP4 style class constructor is not supported since PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784934/use-of-deprecated-php4-style-class-constructor-is-not-supported-since-php-7)

Comment: @Arjan Heh yep came to the same conclusion and had already updated my comment to remove "parent" from it.

Comment: Also note, testimonail is spelled testimonial. (Now picturing what a testimonail is -- some sort of test to ensure your toes only have one covering? Or maybe a QA procedure to ensure you have enough wood fasteners.)

Comment: Sorry, trying to clean up someone's code. The start of the code for one section looks like this:

class asp_testimonail_rotator_widget extends WP_Widget {

 function __construct() {
  parent::__construct( false, 'ASP: Random Testimonial' );
 }
 
 function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  
  extract( $args );
  $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
  $testimonial_category_id = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['category'] );

  global $wpdb;
  global $wp_query;
  $post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
  $parent_page_id = $post_obj->post_parent;

Comment: I updated the function to "function __construct()" and while no error reports occur now... it still think things are not working correctly

Comment: How would y'all recommend remaining it?